# Sql (apache superset) create an id eveytime my data resets

Tags: sql, apache-superset

Hello very new to SQL and working with very complicated data. I'm trying to ID baskets based on  remaning quantity. When value is deacreasing my ID number should hold but when it increases it should change to a new id number (expected column)

```
select id, rem_material
DENSE_RANK() over (Partition by id Order by rem_material DESC ) as ExpectedID
from table
WHERE source ='area 5' and rem_material > 0
```

| Given ID | Basket # | Remaning | Expected ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2150 | 1 | 5400 | 1 |
| 2151 | 1 | 2000 | 1 |
| 2152 | 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2153 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2154 | 5 | 3400 | 2 |
| 2155 | 5 | 2050 | 2 |
| 2156 | 5 | 1010 | 2 |
| 2157 | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 2158 | 1 | 4400 | 3 |
| 2159 | 1 | 3050 | 3 |
| 2160 | 1 | 1500 | 3 |
| 2161 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2162 | 1 | 6000 | 4 |
| 2163 | 1 | 5000 | 4 |
| 2164 | 1 | 4500 | 4 |
| 2165 | 1 | 10 | 4 |

Comment: Please do not link to images. It's preferred to put your sample data AND the expected result as formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to assign a new basket ID whenever the remaining quantity increases. You can achieve this using the LAG window function to compare the current row's rem_material with the previous row's value. If the current value is greater than the previous one, you increment the basket ID; otherwise, you keep the same basket ID.

example code:

```
WITH BasketCTE AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    rem_material,
    LAG(rem_material, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS prev_rem_material
  FROM
    YourTable
  WHERE
    source = 'area 5' AND rem_material > 0
)
SELECT
  id,
  rem_material,
  SUM(CASE WHEN rem_material > prev_rem_material THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OVER (ORDER BY id) AS ExpectedID
FROM
  BasketCTE;
```